# Support negative values

Tags: php

I'm in a situation where the CSV file is getting rid of the leading zero before my import and I need to be able to account for that. Let's say that I have my value as the following:

`-.0982739` -> I would want all case scenarios where it's `-.` to turn into `-0.` - Here are my attempts:

```
if (str_contains($this->longitude, '-.')) {
    $this->longitude = '0' . $this->longitude;
};
Outputs: 00-.0989070

if ($this->longitude[0] == '.') {
    $this->longitude = '0' . $this->longitude;
}
Outputs: -.0989070
```

To simplify things, basically any `.` that has nothing before it, add in a `0`, otherwise use the value given.
I will need it for both longitude and latitude.

Comment: echo sprintf("%f",$this->longitude);

Comment: @JasonK, would this handle all case scenarios, so let's say it's `-.` or `+.` or `.` - If there is no number infront of the period add in a 0, otherwise if there is also `-1.0`, don't change anything.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php Has lots of options. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format is also one to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^([-+])?\./
```

The above regex matches the signs `-` and `+` if they are present and immediately followed by a `.`. Now, capture the matched group 1 in the regex which is `([-+])?` and append `0.` followed by all digits after `.` by taking `substr` of the current string.

```
<?php

$a = ".0982739";

if(preg_match('/^([-+])?\./',$a, $matches) === 1){
    $prefix = $matches[1] ?? '';
    $a = $prefix . '0.' . substr($a,$prefix == '' ? 1 : 2);
}

echo $a;
```

Comment: Nice_dev this is amazing, will it also check for conditionals where it's `.` only? like `.999` - So no positive or negative characters (+, -)?

Comment: @Tripp Yes, you can try it.

Comment: Also, is it possible to account for two variables and output different variables for both, ex: longitude & latitude? Or would I need to call separate if statements? Like if latitude or longitude have +. or -. or . - All this is so helpful!

Comment: @Tripp Please use the updated answer. I fixed an issue.

Comment: @Tripp Call separate if statements for both of them or make a function and call it for both of them following  DRY principle.

Comment: Hey, nice_dev, let's say that if I have `1.9999` already in the DB, I don't want to change any values, it breaks the script, I want to insert only a 0 infront of the decimal if there is no numeric value.

Comment: @Tripp I am not able to reproduce this. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18084191915a549c731fd8a862bbc2c2db58b9a3

Comment: It actually works perfect, I had a var_dump outputting and it was causing errors, thanks so much for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$this->longitude = ltrim($this->longitude, '+');// remove leading +

if ($this->longitude[0]=='.' || substr($this->longitude, 0, 2)=='-.')) {
    $this->longitude = str_replace('.', '0.', $this->longitude);
}
```

The if condition matches any string that begins with '.' or '-.' And if so, str_replace replaces the . with 0.

Comment: @PHP_Guru, how would I handle as such: if the number before a period is NOT an integer, add a zero, keeping any other characters in place.

Comment: "if the number before the period is not an integer"? Can you provide an example of when this would be the case?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones, so let's say that I have any character as such `+.999` or `-.999` or `.999`, this would get turned into `0.999`, otherwise if there is already for example `-1.999`, don't change anything.

Comment: I don't think you would want -.999  to get turned into 0.999

Answer (score 0):

I created a class and assigned `-.0982739` to a property called `$longitude`. In the constructor I did `echo $this->longitude` and it came out as `-0.0982739` which I believe is exactly as you want it to be. I couldn't manage to reproduce it.

```
 <?php

class Test
{
    private $longitude = -.0982739;


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo $this->longitude;
    }
}



<?php
include "Test.php";

$test = new Test();
$test->test();
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you're describing? It's much easier to understand an answer with actual code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <?php

$x = -.54321 ;
echo $x . "\r\n" ;

$x = "-.12345" ;

echo $x . "\r\n" ;

echo floatval($x) . "\r\n" ;

echo sprintf("%0.5f", $x) ; 
?>
```

I assume your CSV is returning only string values, because as soon as I echo a "native" float, the echo is just fine.

As soon as your float is correctly formatted, you can catch it in a string value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`$var = 0.0989070;

$neg = -$var; // easiest
$neg = -1 * $var; // bit more explicit
$neg = 0 - $var; // another version`

Answer (score 0):

You could check for numbers before dot....

```
<?php 

if (str_contains($this->longitude, '.')) {
           $beforedot = strstr($this->longitude,'.',true); //Get anything before
               if (is_numeric($beforedot)) { echo "do nothing";  }  //check if is number do nothing
                    else {   
                        $this->longitude = str_replace('.', '0.', $this->longitude); //else do replace . with 0.
                }
                                         };

?>
```